# Scala Slick auto update a column when the row is updated

Tags: scala, slick

I want add a `updated_at` column for every table.
The column will update its value with current time when the row is updated.

How can I automatic update it's value to avoid writing verbose code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly in the database, don't need to modify your Slick code. you can define it like this, then it will automatically update whenever any value of this row is modified:

`alter table xx add column updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

(this works mysql, not sure if needs adjustment for other databases)

Comment: hi, I know the question was a bit old, but did this work for you or what solution did you find?